# Could not infer the matching function for org.apache.pig.builtin.AVG as multiple or none of them fit. Please use an explicit cast

Tags: apache-pig

I want to calculate average time for question..

```
A= LOAD '/user/priyanka/Book1.csv' AS (qid:chararray,at:datetime);
B= FOREACH A GENERATE qid AS question,(datetime)at AS time;
C= GROUP B BY question;
D= FOREACH C GENERATE group, (datetime) AVG(B.time);
```

getting error here:

> please use explicit cast.

example of qid:56783978 , at: 23:45:30

how to solve?

Answer (score 0):

In your last line you are calling AVG on a bag of datetime records. AVG only works on numeric types.
https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.0/api/org/apache/pig/builtin/AVG.html

You might want to convert your times to unix epochs. You can calculate the average of unix timestamps because they are numeric.
http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.0/api/org/apache/pig/builtin/ToUnixTime.html